# Jquery draggable with safari 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

```
$(".droppable").droppable({
        drop: function(event, ui) {

            var fileName = $(ui.draggable).attr("src").match(/[\/|\\]([^\\\/]+)$/); // get filename.

            var url = $("#hurl").val();
            if ($(ui.draggable).attr('name') == "template")
                url = $("#turl").val();

            var obj = $(ui.draggable).clone().attr("src", url + fileName[1]).css("width", "345px").css("height", "215px");
            $(this).empty();
            obj.draggable({
                    distance: 100,
                    helper: 'clone',
                    opacity: 0.35,
                    revert: 'valid',
                    stop: function(event, ui) {
                        $(this).remove();
                    }

                } //obj.draggable 
            );
            $(this).append(obj);
        }, //drop:

        accept: ".draggable_template"
    }

);
```

The above code worked for IE7, IE6, Firefox 3, Chrome, Opera 10beta, but doesn't work in Safari 4.

The specific problem lies in this piece of code:

```
stop: function(event, ui) { 
    $(this).remove(); 
}
```

In safari 4, this code is not called.

Is there any way to work around this?